# Regex take third element from a space separated list

Tags: regex

I need help to create regular expression for getting the third element from a list such as

```
phrase1 phrase2 phrase3
phrase4 phrase5 phrase6
```

So the result should be

```
phrase3
phrase6
```

What is the regex for this?

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```regex
Find:    ^.*[ ]
Replace: (empty)
```

### Demo

The regex pattern `^.*[ ]` will match everything from the start of the line up to, and including, the final space before the last word in the line.  Then, we replace with nothing, thereby removing the first two (or more) words, leaving behind the third/final word.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to *remove* other items from the string and keep the 3rd one then use [Tim Biegeleisen answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69287487/5923666)**

**If you want to *match* the 3rd item from the string then this answer will help you**

---

You can use this regex:

```regex
^(?:(?:[^\s]+ ){2})([^\s]+)
```

with the `g` and `m` flags

##### Explanation:

**In Words:**

"Jump" over 2 items (item is any string that doesn't have whitespace in it) starting at the beginning of each line and match the 3rd item.

> Whitespace is spaces, tabs, or line breaks

**In Regex:**

Let's break it into pieces:

1. `^`: start of the line (because we using the `m` flag
2. `[^\s]+`: match ant character is not a whitespace character (spaces, tabs, line breaks).
3. `(?:...)`: match but don't include in the matched result
4. `{2}` require 2 items (of the `(?:[^\s]+ )` regex)

##### Notes:

This will match the third item even if there are more items in line:

For example, it'll match `phrase3` and `phrase7` From:

```
phrase1 phrase2 phrase3 phrase4
phrase5 phrase6 phrase7
phrase8
```